# Unable to see full 8GB Ram on ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64

Tags: 16.04, ram, memory-usage

I recently bought new system Lenovo G41-35 and installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS in it.

My ram is of 8GB but due to some reason it shows only `3.3 GiB` in the Details.

How I can use the 8GB Ram in my ubuntu system.

See complete information:

[image]

Below are some commands with output:

`free -m`

Output:

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3354        1080         757          51        1515        1922
Swap:         24412           0       24412
```

`sudo lshw -class memory`

Output:

```
*-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Lenovo
       physical id: 0
       version: C3CN54WW
       date: 11/18/2015
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 8128KiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video pc98 acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 28
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 29
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 2MiB
       capacity: 2MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2a
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 8GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
          product: 9905417-075.A00G
          vendor: Kingston
          physical id: 0
          serial: 2C2602BF
          slot: DIMM 0
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
          product: EBJ40UG8EFU0-GN-F
          vendor: Elpida
          physical id: 1
          serial: 95CB18FD
          slot: DIMM 1
          size: 4GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
```

`uname -a`

Output:

```
Linux muhammad-mohsin 4.8.0-36-generic #36~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sun Feb 5 
09:39:57 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`uname -m`

Output:

```
x86_64
```

`sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 25 "*-memory"`

Output:

```
*-memory
      description: System Memory
      physical id: 2a
      slot: System board or motherboard
      size: 8GiB
    *-bank:0
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
         product: 9905417-075.A00G
         vendor: Kingston
         physical id: 0
         serial: 2C2602BF
         slot: DIMM 0
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
         description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
         product: EBJ40UG8EFU0-GN-F
         vendor: Elpida
         physical id: 1
         serial: 95CB18FD
         slot: DIMM 1
         size: 4GiB
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
 *-pci:0
```

`sudo lshw -short -C memory`

Output:

```
H/W path               Device           Class          Description
==================================================================
/0/0                                    memory         128KiB BIOS
/0/27/28                                memory         256KiB L1 cache
/0/27/29                                memory         2MiB L2 cache
/0/2a                                   memory         8GiB System Memory
/0/2a/0                                 memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
/0/2a/1                                 memory         4GiB SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
```

Comment: You have two different speeds on different RAM chips, 1333 & 1600. Few motherboards support that. Generally best to have same brand also. You can test that each works by unplugging one and boot and then try with other. Linux is not very tolerate of border line RAM where Windows will use it, just not work correctly in background until you have major issues.

Comment: @oldfred I did everything just you have advised. Now it shows `6.7 GiB`. Isn't that should be `7.7 GiB` instead? My other machine shows `7.7 GiB` with 2 modules of 4 4 GB RAMS. Could you please explain? Or may be graphics card is using 1GB? I believe my machine does not have dedicated graphics card installed but a  wild guess if it could be a case. Is there any way I can narrow down the card memory. I even didn't see any graphics card in my BIOS.

Comment: That does seem like a lot for video. But I know very little about AMD graphics and how that works. I have Intel  & nVidia or just Intel on another system.

Comment: @oldfred That makes sense. So, how I could narrow down the RAM for video? Any link or commands?

Comment: You can review these commands: https://askubuntu.com/questions/743649/new-16gb-of-ram-installed-yet-i-see-15-3-on-my-system-why?noredirect=1#comment1106622_743649

Comment: Could you please overlook my question as well? https://askubuntu.com/q/905484/678204