# How do I fix my RAM?

Tags: ram, bios

I have 12GB of ram installed and is recognized by bios. Ubuntu says I only have 9.7GB.

I am running 2 x 4GB and 2 X 2GB. All are DDR3 and I have the larger pair installed in the blue slots (primary) and the smaller sticks in the black slots. The motherboard is a MSI 970A-G43 that can take up to 32GB. I have a 256MB gpu card installed and the motherboard does not have on board video.

I have installed each pair of memory (in the blue slots) without the other and they all are good.

I know it is ill-advised to install ram of different sizes/type, but I feel like if BIOS sees it, Ubuntu should too. How can I correct this?

Comment: Check this, especially the diagnostic commands in the answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/743649/new-16gb-of-ram-installed-yet-i-see-15-3-on-my-system-why

Comment: Using his tools, I could account for about 10GB (9.7GB shown in details and .14GB from `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Slab
`). Still over 2GB missing somewhere. Nothing happened as of a result of: `dmesg | grep stolen`. `sudo dmidecode | grep Size | grep MB` show all of the sticks properly.