# Ubuntu 20.04 boot and performance post login is very slow

Tags: boot, performance, disk

My Ubuntu is very slow to boot and freezes constantly, even saving a file and exiting the editor takes a very long time. The system just freezes after an hour of usage and its very slow to use any program like Chrome as you have to wait for some time every time you open or browse a tab

```
cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS"

uname -a
Linux gilead 5.10.0-1050-oem #52-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 6 12:58:49 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             3890308        0   3890308   0% /dev
tmpfs             786744     2188    784556   1% /run
/dev/sda3      951292564 53517336 849382476   6% /
tmpfs            3933720   275708   3658012   8% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            3933720        0   3933720   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         56960    56960         0 100% /snap/core18/2620
/dev/loop2         56960    56960         0 100% /snap/core18/2632
/dev/loop3        117760   117760         0 100% /snap/core/14056
/dev/loop5         56448    56448         0 100% /snap/cups/836
/dev/loop4        168832   168832         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop8         93952    93952         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop7         55552    55552         0 100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop1        224256   224256         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/loop10        64768    64768         0 100% /snap/core20/1634
/dev/loop6           128      128         0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop13        83328    83328         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop12       354688   354688         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop11       224256   224256         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop16        47104    47104         0 100% /snap/snap-store/599
/dev/loop9        149120   149120         0 100% /snap/chromium/2188
/dev/loop17       117760   117760         0 100% /snap/core/13886
/dev/loop15       354688   354688         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop14       148864   148864         0 100% /snap/chromium/2193
/dev/loop18       166784   166784         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop19        64768    64768         0 100% /snap/core20/1695
/dev/sda1         840704    34788    805916   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs             786744       36    786708   1% /run/user/1001
```

I have attached the logs from sudo journalctl -b0. Refer https://pastebin.com/D3bmvcgh

```
free 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        7867448     2164864     3112716      495808     2589868     4905968
Swap:       2097148           0     2097148


df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             972578    605   971973    1% /dev
tmpfs            983431   1215   982216    1% /run
/dev/sda3      60473344 823847 59649497    2% /
tmpfs            983431    145   983286    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            983431      4   983427    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            983431     18   983413    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1        27806  27806        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
/dev/loop5        76208  76208        0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop6        10873  10873        0  100% /snap/core18/2620
/dev/loop0         2587   2587        0  100% /snap/cups/836
/dev/loop2        11885  11885        0  100% /snap/core20/1634
/dev/loop11       10873  10873        0  100% /snap/core18/2632
/dev/loop7           29     29        0  100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop10       12848  12848        0  100% /snap/core/14056
/dev/loop9        27807  27807        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop13       76177  76177        0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
/dev/loop14       17275  17275        0  100% /snap/snap-store/599
/dev/loop12       18121  18121        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
/dev/loop8        17311  17311        0  100% /snap/snap-store/558
/dev/loop4         1004   1004        0  100% /snap/chromium/2188
/dev/loop15       18272  18272        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
/dev/loop17        1004   1004        0  100% /snap/chromium/2193
/dev/loop16       12845  12845        0  100% /snap/core/13886
/dev/loop19       18500  18500        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop18       11897  11897        0  100% /snap/core20/1695
/dev/loop3        18500  18500        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
/dev/sda1             0      0        0     - /boot/efi
tmpfs            983431     95   983336    1% /run/user/1001
```

EDIT 1: Unable to launch my terminal nor my browser as it keeps spinning

EDIT 2:

```
systemd-analyze blame
1min 26.374s fstrim.service                                       
     55.496s plymouth-quit-wait.service                           
     29.394s snapd.service                                        
     27.532s docker.service                                       
     23.801s containerd.service                                   
     23.387s networkd-dispatcher.service                          
     20.075s systemd-journal-flush.service                        
     19.395s NetworkManager-wait-online.service                   
     19.152s dev-sda3.device                                      
     14.893s udisks2.service                                      
      9.877s accounts-daemon.service                              
      8.088s polkit.service                                       
      7.966s avahi-daemon.service                                 
      7.964s bluetooth.service                                    
      7.956s NetworkManager.service                               
      7.588s dev-loop0.device                                     
      7.443s switcheroo-control.service                           
      7.438s thermald.service                                     
      7.436s systemd-logind.service                               
      7.436s wpa_supplicant.service                               
      7.198s systemd-modules-load.service                         
      6.882s dev-loop6.device                                     
      6.853s dev-loop12.device                                    
      6.383s dev-loop11.device                                    
      6.302s dev-loop3.device                                     
      6.079s dev-loop19.device                                    
      5.839s dev-loop13.device                                    
      5.809s dev-loop14.device                                    
      5.794s dev-loop9.device                                     
      5.637s dev-loop10.device                                    
      5.495s systemd-random-seed.service                          
      5.410s dev-loop8.device                                     
      5.246s dev-loop7.device                                     
      5.024s dev-loop2.device                                     
      5.006s dev-loop16.device                                    
      4.834s dev-loop5.device                                     
      4.821s dev-loop4.device                                     
      4.763s dev-loop18.device                                    
      4.531s dev-loop15.device                                    
      4.345s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                   
      3.938s dev-loop17.device                                    
      3.861s gpu-manager.service                                  
      3.482s dev-loop1.device                                     
      3.259s grub-common.service                                  
      3.025s keyboard-setup.service                               
      2.689s ssh.service                                          
      2.689s preload.service                                      
      2.631s secureboot-db.service                                
      2.576s gdm.service                                          
      2.448s rsyslog.service                                      
      2.390s systemd-udevd.service                                
      2.321s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                       
      2.223s systemd-udev-trigger.service                         
      2.214s apport.service                                       
      2.146s ufw.service                                          
      2.050s apparmor.service                                     
      1.886s fwupd.service                                        
      1.853s systemd-remount-fs.service                           
      1.706s tlp.service                                          
      1.607s snap-core-14056.mount                                
      1.598s e2scrub_reap.service                                 
      1.490s systemd-sysusers.service                             
      1.414s snap-core18-2632.mount                               
      1.360s systemd-sysctl.service                               
      1.202s snap-core18-2620.mount                               
      1.136s snap-cups-836.mount                                  
      1.125s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-119.mount              
      1.125s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-16A4\x2dF313.service
      1.038s snap-core20-1695.mount                               
       985ms snapd.apparmor.service                               
       981ms snap-core-13886.mount                                
       922ms swapfile.swap                                        
       802ms grub-initrd-fallback.service                         
       734ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-145.mount              
       726ms snap-bare-5.mount                                    
       710ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-77.mount               
       682ms snap-chromium-2193.mount                             
       647ms snap-snap\x2dstore-558.mount                         
       630ms boot-efi.mount                                       
       621ms lvm2-monitor.service                                 
       590ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-161.mount              
       579ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-72.mount               
       561ms snap-chromium-2221.mount                             
       557ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1534.mount              
       554ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount              
       550ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-115.mount              
       539ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                       
       535ms upower.service                                       
       505ms snap-snap\x2dstore-599.mount                         
       477ms systemd-journald.service                             
       476ms dev-hugepages.mount                                  
       474ms dev-mqueue.mount                                     
       473ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                               
       472ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                             
       464ms pppd-dns.service                                     
       461ms blk-availability.service                             
       461ms kmod-static-nodes.service                            
       460ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service                          
       459ms modprobe@ramoops.service                             
       455ms snapd.seeded.service                                 
       321ms kerneloops.service                                   
       300ms motd-news.service                                    
       255ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service  
       220ms systemd-timesyncd.service                            
       199ms rtkit-daemon.service                                 
       198ms snap-core20-1634.mount                               
       193ms alsa-restore.service                                 
       186ms openvpn.service                                      
       159ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount                        
       124ms user@1001.service                                    
       121ms console-setup.service                                
       119ms setvtrgb.service                                     
       106ms systemd-user-sessions.service                        
        77ms systemd-update-utmp.service                          
        66ms systemd-resolved.service                             
        64ms modprobe@chromeos_pstore.service                     
        17ms user-runtime-dir@1001.service                        
        12ms plymouth-start.service                               
        12ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service   
        11ms ModemManager.service                                 
        11ms plymouth-read-write.service                          
         6ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                 
         4ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                        
         2ms sys-kernel-config.mount                              
         2ms modprobe@pstore_blk.service                          
         2ms finalrd.service                                      
         2ms docker.socket                                        
         1ms modprobe@pstore_zone.service                         
         1ms snapd.socket
```

EDIT 3: Output from fstrim

```
journalctl -u fstrim

-- Logs begin at Thu 2022-11-03 12:01:24 IST, end at Mon 2022-11-28 11:32:20 IST. --
Nov 07 07:14:22 gilead systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
-- Reboot --
Nov 14 07:40:24 gilead systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
Nov 14 07:44:20 gilead fstrim[313357]: /boot/efi: 787 MiB (825257984 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
Nov 14 07:44:20 gilead fstrim[313357]: /: 858.4 GiB (921678942208 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda3
Nov 14 07:44:20 gilead systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Nov 14 07:44:20 gilead systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.
-- Reboot --
Nov 21 06:28:29 gilead systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
Nov 21 07:36:49 gilead fstrim[204538]: /boot/efi: 787 MiB (825257984 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
Nov 21 07:36:49 gilead fstrim[204538]: /: 857.1 GiB (920249229312 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda3
Nov 21 07:36:47 gilead systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Nov 21 07:36:47 gilead systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.
-- Reboot --
Nov 28 09:12:55 gilead systemd[1]: Starting Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab...
Nov 28 09:14:23 gilead fstrim[1118]: /boot/efi: 787 MiB (825257984 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda1
Nov 28 09:14:23 gilead fstrim[1118]: /: 856.3 GiB (919475277824 bytes) trimmed on /dev/sda3
Nov 28 09:14:23 gilead systemd[1]: fstrim.service: Succeeded.
Nov 28 09:14:23 gilead systemd[1]: Finished Discard unused blocks on filesystems from /etc/fstab.
```

EDIT 4:

```
lsblk -d -e 7 -o NAME,ROTA,DISC-MAX,MODEL
NAME ROTA DISC-MAX MODEL
sda     1       2G ST1000LM035-1RK172
```

EDIT 5:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a14 (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a0ed (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a0ef (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e8 (rev 20)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e9 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e0 (rev 20)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device a0d3 (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b0 (rev 20)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b1 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a082 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a0a3 (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0a4 (rev 20)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Et
```

EDIT 6:

```
sudo lshw -c storage -c disk
  *-sata                    
       description: SATA controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 17
       bus info: pci@0000:00:17.0
       version: 20
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: sata msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
       resources: irq:125 memory:70b00000-70b01fff memory:70b04000-70b040ff ioport:4080(size=8) ioport:4088(size=4) ioport:4060(size=32) memory:70b03000-70b037ff
  *-scsi
       physical id: a
       logical name: scsi0
       capabilities: emulated
     *-disk
          description: ATA Disk
          product: ST1000LM035-1RK1
          physical id: 0.0.0
          bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
          logical name: /dev/sda
          version: 1002
          serial: WKPLQM26
          size: 931GiB (1TB)
          capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
          configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=1c7719c4-6f41-42d1-b542-67a2bcbbe758 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
```

EDIT 7: Output from smartctl

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda3 
smartctl 7.1 2019-12-30 r5022 [x86_64-linux-5.14.0-1054-oem] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-19, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Mobile HDD
Device Model:     ST1000LM035-1RK172
Serial Number:    WKPLQM26
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0d5ceb077
Firmware Version: 1002
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Dec  1 20:13:12 2022 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x71) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 167) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x3035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   079   064   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       87816166
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   097   097   020    Old_age   Always       -       3729
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   075   060   045    Pre-fail  Always       -       31083756
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1463 (24 10 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   020    Old_age   Always       -       215
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       3145781
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   062   055   040    Old_age   Always       -       38 (Min/Max 36/40)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       76
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       87
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       3829
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   038   045   000    Old_age   Always       -       38 (0 24 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       710 (41 71 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       1452420411
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2297508873
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

EDIT 8:

```
sudo lsblk
    NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
    loop0    7:0    0 116.7M  1 loop /snap/core/14399
    loop1    7:1    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
    loop2    7:2    0 164.8M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
    loop3    7:3    0  91.7M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
    loop4    7:4    0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1634
    loop5    7:5    0     4K  1 loop /snap/bare/5
    loop6    7:6    0 146.6M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2229
    loop7    7:7    0 145.3M  1 loop /snap/chromium/2221
    loop8    7:8    0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2620
    loop9    7:9    0   219M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
    loop10   7:10   0    46M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/638
    loop11   7:11   0  63.2M  1 loop /snap/core20/1695
    loop12   7:12   0  55.6M  1 loop /snap/core18/2632
    loop13   7:13   0  55.1M  1 loop /snap/cups/836
    loop14   7:14   0  81.3M  1 loop /snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
    loop15   7:15   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/115
    loop16   7:16   0 346.3M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-38-2004/119
    loop17   7:17   0  45.9M  1 loop /snap/snap-store/599
    loop18   7:18   0 162.9M  1 loop /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
    sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
    ├─sda1   8:1    0   825M  0 part /boot/efi
    ├─sda2   8:2    0     8G  0 part 
    └─sda3   8:3    0 922.7G  0 part /
```

EDIT 9:

```
sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST1000LM035-1RK1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  866MB   865MB   fat32        EFI system partition  boot, esp
 2      866MB   9456MB  8590MB  fat32        Basic data partition  msftres
 3      9456MB  1000GB  991GB   ext4
```

Comment: please add also the output of `df -i` and `free`

Comment: done, have added

Comment: maybe take a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356353/system-freezes-when-ram-limit-reached-doesnt-use-swap)

Comment: I have 8GB RAM, do you want to increase the swap space

Comment: For your slow boot: what does `systemd-analyze blame` tell? Copy the output and add it to your question.

Comment: I have added that information @kanehekili

Comment: Your output shows that you are starting both docker and containerd at boot, which seems both resource-intensive and duplicative. You have installed a lot of applications and services. Disable or uninstall those that you are not using anymore. And something is wrong with your sda3 -- investigate and fix.

Comment: I will try and uninstall docker for the time being, the purge process is still running for quite sometime. How do I debug what is wrong with sda3 is it the primary disk?

Comment: I have added output from fstrim as well

Comment: What type of disk is the os on?

Comment: I've added disk information @BilboBaggins

Comment: Like others have said it's probably your HDD. I think that's an HDD you're using.

Comment: An easy way to test this is to make a live USB of Ubuntu and boot from that. See if you can test the Live USB and see if it works better than your HDD installation to rule out other hardware on your system.

Comment: You can test using your terminal to create and edit files. Does it take a while to create and edit them? Run some program to test your HDD usage.

Answer (score 0):

The times of analyze-blame indicate that your hard disk is either failing or gets altered. Fstrim should not run every time you start.

One "culprit" could be another OS on the same hardware. Gnome "disks" provides you with a health state of your hard disk, check it out.

You could disable the fstrim service (temporarily) in order to check if that service slows you down.

Rinzwind has described this [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165169/906933).

But disabling that service will not solve your problem: You have to find out what happens to your disk. fstrim removes unused blocks. So something must put these blocks there in the first place.

IF you use an encrypted drive, you might have to reconfigure fstrim (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dm-crypt/Specialties#Discard/TRIM_support_for_solid_state_drives_(SSD)) for encryption on SSD

Comment: There is no other OS on the Dell hardware

Comment: I don't use encrypted drive, its just factory setup of a Dell machine

Comment: Use `smartmontools` to check the health of your drive

Comment: I have attached output from smartctl as part of the description